# Binary Comparison Between Two Integers

Tags: arithmetic, binary

Say I have two integers,i and j, which for the sake of example will be 2 and 5, represented by $010_2$ and $101_2$ respectively. I have a third bit set to 0. If $j \geq i$, then this bit should change to 1. I am trying to understand how in principle this is done. My understanding is if you flip the bits in j, and then perform binary addition of the two numbers, the most significant bit will be 1 if $j \geq i$, and 0 otherwise. Can someone explain how this works, and how to implement this in terms of logic gates?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Please tell what are the inputs to the problem? What is the expected output. I do not understand this statement: "I have a third bit set to $0$. If $j≥i$, then this bit should change to $1$." What are $i$ and $j$? etc.